# C# - Searching across more than one column

Tags: c#

Two questions:

1. How would you merge the two bits of code? Seems a bit redundant to have them as two large chunks!
2. How would you go about searching by more than one column (and return a result if it is found in any of the following columns: *name, gender, age*)?

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
           bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
           bs.Filter = "id like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
           dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
   }

   private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
           BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
           bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
           bs.Filter = "id like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
           dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
   }
   ```

Comment: why can't you write a function and call it instead of writing it multiple times?

Comment: @Sudhakar I'm pretty new to C#

Comment: Is [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) required feature of your code? Please use parametrized SQL queries.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm connecting to a local DB source (i.e. a Access database)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: how do you get sql injection out of a bindingsource filter?  Isn't that executed locally (in the bindingsource class), after the data has been retrieved from wherever it came from?

Comment: @jmoreno - I did not realized that this way of setting filter does not allow to use parametrized queries - not sure why it was designed this way... I guess OP will enjoy dealing with SQL injections as result. There is probably way to completely ignore that portion of the class and do filtering on other level. May be good followup question.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: no SQL injection, because no sql is involved.  The bindingsource is a "client" side process -- you get 10,000 rows back from the sql server and want to filter your display down to just a few hundred.  He doesn't say so, but it's probably a winform application (that's where it generally makes the most sense).  Again, no sql involved -- in fact the datasource may not evn be a datatable.

Comment: @jmoreno I used "SQL injection" in more generic sense - probably wrong... What if `textBox1.Text = "\" or true or id like \""` or something similar? Depending if user is friendly or hostile it may make difference... Obviously less interesting than directly talking to DB, but still dangerous.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: then the user either gets the same result as textBox1.Text ="", or zero rows returned. so, not dangerous.  This is used for dynamic results, not security.  Of couse, it could be used for security, but in my opinion, that would be a misuse of the class.  It's intened for just what the name says - taking a list of values that are displayed to the user and letting the user enter a value that reduces the size of the list, i.e. filtering. Not controlling what elements in the list the user is **allowed** to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to your 1st Question :**

Create a function to have your searching statements and call it whenever you required.as below:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           SearchData();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             SearchData();
        }
        private void SearchData()
        {
            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
            bs.Filter = "id like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
         }
```

**Answer to your 2nd Question :**

you can write Filter as below:

```
bs.Filter = "id like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%' and name like '%" + textBox2.Text + "%'";
```